# Static images are not displayed every time

Tags: react-native

I'm writing an application that should work without internet connection, so all my pictures (jpeg) are distributed with application itself. I'm using:

```
const IMAGES = [
   require('../../images/animals/agamaKocincinska/01.jpg'),
   require('../../images/animals/agamaKocincinska/02.jpg'), 
];
```

and lated I render them:

```
    <Image
      source={this.props.thumbnails[this.props.index]}
      resizeMode='cover'
      style={this.props.imageStyle}
    />
```

This works perfectly with iOS (simulator+real device), images are loaded consistently on Android simulator too. On the real devices (multiple, various Android releases) images are mostly shown after application starts but after few scenes, they are not displayed. This happends quite randomly but with increased occasionality. Displaying images is not consistent even on one phone. Do you have any ideas, how to test, where is the issue?

Comment: When you're running on device, are you using the offline bundle or still serving the bundle.js file through your local packager server?

Comment: Mentioned issue are with offline bundle. I have just re-tested that bundle.js works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to memory issue.

Open android manifest file and add below code in your application tag.

`android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: @Marek Grác : have you try this solution?

Comment: Sorry, it took me longer than I have expected. Unfortunately this did not help. My application has ~70MB so it should fit in largeHeap easilly